# Css scroll snap + js tracking

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, прокрутка

Подскажите, каким образом можно присваивать index слайдам, созданным через css scroll snap?

Задумка в следующем: по-центру экрана слайдер для картинок, каждая картинка с уникальным айди, а снизу страницы расположена кнопка, которая должна каким-то образом узнать какой слайд находится на экране в момент клика по ней.

Обошел весь интернет, толком ничего не понял…